# cannot import name 'CenterCrop' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using anaconda env.

Python 3.7
keras : 2.3.1
tensorflow: 2.1.0

when i want to use CenterCrop and Rescaling modules, pycharm gives me error.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import CenterCrop
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Rescaling
```

error messages is:

```
D:\NewAnaconda\envs\Tensor_Turkcell\python.exe "C:/Users/Burak Ekincioğlu/Dekstop/TENSORFLOW/tensor_intro.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Burak Ekincioğlu/Dekstop/TENSORFLOW/tensor_intro.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import CenterCrop
ImportError: cannot import name 'CenterCrop' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' (D:\NewAnaconda\envs\Tensor_Turkcell\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\api\_v2\keras\layers\experimental\preprocessing\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the import with tensorflow 2.1.0 (keras 2.2.4 by default) and it gave me the same error you are encountering.

Using Tensorflow 2.2.0 with keras 2.3.0 works fine.

So you just need to upgrade tensorflow.

Comment: in anaconda i can install mostly tensorflow==2.1.0 , there is not available tensorflow==2.2.0, did you install on anaconda environment ? , thanks

Comment: i have tested it on google colaboratory. I have checked on anaconda and it doesn't show tensorflow 2.2.0, but it still seems possible to install it with `pip install tensorflow==2.2.0`

Comment: thank you for your interest. I have installed succesfully, than there is another error: ImportError: DLL load failed: Specified module cannot find --

Comment: okay, i delete tensorflow completely, and than install tensorflow==2.2.0 again, and it is SOLVED, thank s for interest.